# In Android Oreo 8.0 App is coming foreground from background when notification come

Tags: android, notifications, android-8.0-oreo

My app is coming to the foreground while app in background state when notification come but This behavior is not happening in the killed state.
This is not happening below oreo.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, getString(R.string.app_name), NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
    notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
}

NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this,CHANNEL_ID)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.tracking_app_logo)
        .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
        .setContentText("Uploading database...")
        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
        .setAutoCancel(false)
        .setChannelId(CHANNEL_ID)
        .setOngoing(true)
        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH);


startForeground(102, mBuilder.build());
```

Answer (score 1):

What is happening is that you are creating the notification in your own activity context and never launching it from a background service, so if you don't kill the app you will be able to see the notification since the context is still alive and the notification can be created.

You should use `AlarmManager` to schedule your notifications, since you are using it in your own activity context, I would recommend you to read about `AlarmManager` service and how to get it done with notifications.

A good article on how to achieve this can be find here
http://droidmentor.com/schedule-notifications-using-alarmmanager/

How it works is basic:

First you setup a background service such as the `AlarmManager` to launch the notifications of your app in the background

`AlarmManager` will set a time to the notification and even if the app is killed it will launch your notification since `AlarmManager` is a service that runs in the system background.

Another tip is to use Firebase cloud messaging service combined with NotificationCompat; you just need to implement the service in your manifest like this to run notifications in background

```
<service
    android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Check Firebase messaging documentation : https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client

Comment: Thanks for such a good explanation but I am calling a service from a job scheduler and in the service I am creating the notification. Actually, I just don't want the app to come in the foreground while notification comes.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for that if you find this answer irrelevant, I posted this because I thought you are using push notification but now I think you are generating notification from with in the application let me know if I am again going in wrong direction.

You can generate notification from in the application by following ways.

1. Alarm Manager:
   In this you can specify the time when you need the notification so when the requirement are met you can pass the Broadcast to app so that event will be triggered

   eg: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager
2. Service:
   In this you can start the sticky service that will run in the background and when the condition will met then your broadcast will get fired and you can show your notification

   eg: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service
3. Job scheduler:
   By using this you can also show the notification you want to show

   eg: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidTaskScheduling/article.html

and if you are still facing this issue please go through this link:

https://medium.com/exploring-android/exploring-background-execution-limits-on-android-oreo-ab384762a66c